# Como somar valores de dentro de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python

Fiz um código que armazena dados em um dicionário, e o dicionário é armazenado em uma lista, mas quando eu tento somar e dividir os valores, a primeira média é a que acaba valendo para todos os alunos.

```
print('RU do aluno: - ')

alunos = []
notas = []
N = int(input('Qual o número de alunos? '))
for i in range(N):
    boletim = {'nome' : 0, 'n1' : 0, 'n2' : 0, 'n3' : 0, 'n4' : 0, 'media' :0}
    boletim['nome'] = input('Digite o nome do aluno: ')
    boletim['n1'] = float(input('Digite a primeira nota: '))
    boletim['n2'] = float(input('Digite a segunda nota: '))
    boletim['n3'] = float(input('Digite a terceira nota: '))
    boletim['n4'] = float(input('Digite a quarta nota: '))
    boletim ['media'] = boletim ['n1'], boletim ['n2'], boletim ['n3'], boletim ['n4']
    alunos.append(boletim)
    notas.append(boletim['media'])
    soma_das_notas = 0
    for nota in notas[0]:
        soma_das_notas += nota
    boletim['media'] = soma_das_notas / 4
    if boletim['media'] >= 7:
        boletim['media'] = 'aprovado'
    else:
        boletim['media'] = 'reprovado'
print('\nNota dos alunos')
print('-' * 90)
for aluno in alunos:
    print(f'{aluno["nome"]}       {aluno["n1"]}   {aluno["n2"]}   {aluno["n3"]}   {aluno["n4"]}   {aluno["media"]}')
```

Ele me retorna o seguinte:

[image: esse é o retorno, a nota da média do primeiro aluno cadastrado é a que fica para todos.]

Comment: Eu consideraria trocar essa estrutura de dados veja [esse exemplo](https://ideone.com/hCjgzO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, amigo. Bom, o erro está acontecendo, mais especificamente, por causa da linha 17 do seu código:

```
for nota in notas[0]:
```

Você definiu o cálculo somente para o primeiro elemento da lista notas, o elemento 0. Logo, a média só será calculada com as notas do primeiro aluno cadastrado. Uma opção bem simples para resolver o problema é acrescentar uma variável no início do código com valor igual a 0 e, em cada repetição do loop, somar 1 a esta variável, de modo que o índice acompanhará a quantidade de alunos na lista.

No código abaixo, escolhi a variável z para executar o que expliquei.

```
  print('RU do aluno: - ')

alunos = []
notas = []
z = 0 #Definindo a variável
N = int(input('Qual o número de alunos? '))
for i in range(N):
    boletim = {'nome' : 0, 'n1' : 0, 'n2' : 0, 'n3' : 0, 'n4' : 0, 'media' :0}
    boletim['nome'] = input('Digite o nome do aluno: ')
    boletim['n1'] = float(input('Digite a primeira nota: '))
    boletim['n2'] = float(input('Digite a segunda nota: '))
    boletim['n3'] = float(input('Digite a terceira nota: '))
    boletim['n4'] = float(input('Digite a quarta nota: '))
    boletim ['media'] = boletim ['n1'], boletim ['n2'], boletim ['n3'], boletim ['n4']
    alunos.append(boletim)
    notas.append(boletim['media'])
    soma_das_notas = 0
    for nota in notas[z]: #Garantindo que o índice acompanhará o número de alunos
        soma_das_notas += nota
    boletim['media'] = soma_das_notas / 4
    if boletim['media'] >= 7:
        boletim['media'] = 'aprovado'
    else:
        boletim['media'] = 'reprovado'

    z += 1
print('\nNota dos alunos')
print('-' * 90)
for aluno in alunos:
    print(f'{aluno["nome"]}       {aluno["n1"]}   {aluno["n2"]}   {aluno["n3"]}   {aluno["n4"]}   {aluno["media"]}')
```

Essas duas pequenas alterações devem resolver o problema. Avise-me se consegui ajudar você. Boa sorte!

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado, você me ajudou muito.